# JQuery replace var value

Tags: jquery

I have the following code.

```
var fancyProductDesigner = jQuery('#fancy-product-designer-310938')
                        .fancyProductDesigner({
                            uploadDesigns: 0,
                            customTexts: 1,
                            imageDownloadable: 1,
                            saveAsPdf: 0,
                            printable: 1,
                            dimensions: {
                                sidebarNavSize: 30,
                                sidebarContentWidth: 168,
                                sidebarSize: 887,
                                productStageWidth: 490,
                                productStageHeight: 490
                            }
                        }).data('fancy-product-designer');
```

I want to change the width and height. locations are in (dimensions:) with user inputted dimension.

I need to know how I can set/change these values.

I already tried to see if the object exists.

```
alert(typeof $('fancy-product-designer').data('dimensions'));
```

But it says undefined....

My page is at http://www.panel-it.eu/shop/ontwerp-sticker-effe-kleuren/#

And the element appears when pressing the yellow bar.

---

I am logging

```
 console.log(jQuery('#fancy-product-designer-310938').data('fancy-product-designer'));
```

But can't find a way to reset dimension.

I noticed: setStageDimensions

Can somebody help me along?

Comment: uhh, I just checked your panel-it.eu site, and JQuery isn't actually defined... Did you remember to include the file?

Comment: @DylanCorriveau jQuery is defined there. Use `jQuery` not `$`.

Comment: I don't know fancyProductDesigner and didn't find a documentation quickly, but are you sure, the data function sets the attributes, you defined before?

Answer (score 0):

This returns an object with all methods available for fancy product designer:

```
var data = jQuery('#fancy-product-designer-310938').data('fancy-product-designer');
```

Inside you find a method `setStageDimensions()` that you can use like so:

```
// first argument is the width, second the height
data.setStageDimensions(200, 400);
```

Now inside dimensions `productStageWidth` is 200 and `productStageHeight` is 400. A method to change the other dimensions I can't find. As @boulder_02 mentioned in his comment the data method doesn't store your original object but its own returned by `.fancyProductDesigner()`.